# Replacement IC for the touch-button QT1081?

Tags: integrated-circuit, button, capacitive, capsense

A project I'm working on needs several touch buttons. I found the datasheet for the Atmel [QT1081](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Atmel%20PDFs/QT1081.pdf), which supports up to 8 capacitive buttons, with the added advantage for our circuit that there are separate outputs for each button, driven high when the button is pressed.

Unfortunately, this IC appears to be no longer available -- it's out of stock almost everywhere I've checked, and it looks as though it's been replaced by chips that use interfaces like I2C or SPI, which would complicate matters for our system, and require a redesign.

Does anyone know if there are other ICs around that support capacitive buttons, and which also provide a straightforward pin-per-button output?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atmel AT42QT1060 has I2C and Discrete -> 6 channels.

The 7 channel and 8 channels are I2C only it seems as you noted.  So you could use 2 of these chips to get 12 if 6 isn't enough.

and [here](http://www.smsc.com/Products/Capacitive_Touch_Sensors/CAP1188) is a 8 channel from uChip.

Comment: Thanks for that -- I'd looked at others, and completely missed that the 1060 supported discrete lines.